# When adding JPanel to BorderLayout.Center previous content remains visible

Tags: java, border-layout

I have a program with a static header (BorderLayout.NORTH) and footer (BorderLayout.SOUTH) and was attempting to cycle different JPanel's for the body (BorderLayout.CENTER) using action listeners on a JComboBox in my header. As I understood BorderLayout, each time I added a JPanel (or any component) to the CENTER (or anywhere else in the layout) it would overwrite the old content. That mostly happens, but the new CENTER retains the outline of the previous JPanel over the top of it (just the outline as I removeAll() from the panel).

I've been googling this expecting that I've done a common mistake, but all I'm seeing is people trying to negate the overwrite ability which I can't seem to trigger. Tried several different fixes (a single Jpanel declared as an instance variable and then changing it's content using removeAll/revalidate/repaint, creating separate panel's and adding them, etc...).

I'll include the majority of the code below but here is my constructor:

```
public UserInterface(Operator o, LocalDate d) {
    DefaultDateModel model = new DefaultDateModel(d);
    user = o; 

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //setup Menus
    if (user.getAccessPrivs().equalsIgnoreCase("OPRTR")) {
        OperatorMenus menu = new OperatorMenus(); 
        setJMenuBar(menu); }
    else if (user.getAccessPrivs().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
        AdminMenus menu = new AdminMenus(); 
        setJMenuBar(menu); }
    else {
        GalileoMenus menu = new GalileoMenus();
        setJMenuBar(menu); }

    //creates header with navigation buttons
    add(new NavButtons(model), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //loads content 
    viewConstructor(model); 

    //creates footer
    JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        footer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        footer.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        focusPoint = new JLabel(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E, dd MMM yyyy").format(model.getDate()));
            focusPoint.setForeground(Color.RED);
        footer.add(focusPoint, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JLabel loggedIn = new JLabel(user.getName(), JLabel.RIGHT);
            loggedIn.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
        footer.add(loggedIn, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH); }
```

...and the method I use to modify the body:

```
public void viewConstructor(DefaultDateModel m) {
    DefaultDateModel model = m;

    //removeAll();
    body.removeAll();
    body.revalidate();
    body.repaint();
    getContentPane().remove(body);
    //body = new JPanel();
    //body.revalidate();
    //body.repaint();
    //body.updateUI();
    //body.setOpaque(false);

    //set window frame's title
    if      (panelZone == MYVIEW) { setTitle("My View"); }
    else if (panelZone == OPERTR) { setTitle("Operations"); }
    else if (panelZone == SHIFTS) { setTitle("Scheduling"); }
    else if (panelZone == FISCAL) { setTitle("Fiscal Report"); } 

    //builds body panel
    if (panelZone == MYVIEW) {
        add(new JScrollPane(buildMyView(model.getDate())), BorderLayout.CENTER); }

    else if (panelZone == OPERTR) {
        add(new JScrollPane(buildOperatorView(model.getDate())), BorderLayout.CENTER); }

    else if (panelZone == SHIFTS) {
        add(new JScrollPane(buildSchedulingView(model.getDate())), BorderLayout.CENTER); }

    else if (panelZone == FISCAL) {
        add(new JScrollPane(buildFiscalView(model.getDate())), BorderLayout.CENTER); }

    validate();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    pack(); }
```

I know I should put more comments, etc... but I put those methods up separately because the rest is kinda messy right now and that seems to be the problem area. For completeness sake here's a screenshot of the problem and the rest of the code segment (I call `UserInterface frame = new UserInterface(Current_User);` in my main and that's about it).

[image: the residual "under construction" is from the default MyView panel]

*Note* Tried to include the rest of my code but hit the character limit. If anyone want's me to post more of the content I'll reply with whatever method they think is an issue.

***Update***
Realized I was using JScrollPane, so I created an instance variable:
`private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();`
so I could .removeAll() + revalidate() + repaint() `pane`

Now I've just got nothing in the body. Here's where my method is at:

```
public void viewConstructor(DefaultDateModel m) {
    DefaultDateModel model = m;
pane.removeAll();

//set window frame's title
    if      (panelZone == MYVIEW) { setTitle("My View"); }
    else if (panelZone == OPERTR) { setTitle("Operations"); }
    else if (panelZone == SHIFTS) { setTitle("Scheduling"); }
    else if (panelZone == FISCAL) { setTitle("Fiscal Report"); } 

    //builds body panel
//      JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        if (panelZone == MYVIEW) {
 //         add(new JScrollPane(buildMyView(model.getDate())), BorderLayout.CENTER); }
        pane.setViewportView(buildMyView(model.getDate())); }

    else if (panelZone == OPERTR) {
    //  add(new JScrollPane(buildOperatorView(model.getDate())), BorderLayout.CENTER); }
        pane.setViewportView(buildOperatorView(model.getDate())); }

    else if (panelZone == SHIFTS) {
//      add(new JScrollPane(buildSchedulingView(model.getDate())), BorderLayout.CENTER); }
        pane.setViewportView(buildSchedulingView(model.getDate())); }

    else if (panelZone == FISCAL) {
//          add(new JScrollPane(buildFiscalView(model.getDate()))); }
        pane.setViewportView(buildFiscalView(model.getDate())); }       

    //validate();
//      body.revalidate();
//      body.repaint();
    pane.revalidate();
    pane.repaint();
    //repaint();
    pack(); }
```

***SSCCE***

```
package interfaceComponents;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5249508445298805323L;
private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
private int stage = 0;

public SSCCE() {
    JPanel header = new JPanel(); 
        JButton cycler = new JButton("Cycle");
        cycler.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {         
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                stage++;
                if (stage == 3) { stage = 0; }
                buildBody(); }
        });
        header.add(cycler);
    add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buildBody();

    JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        footer.add(new JLabel("Random Text"));
    add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH); }

public void buildBody() {
    JPanel body = new JPanel();
        if      (stage == 0) { body.setBackground(Color.RED); }
        else if (stage == 1) { body.setBackground(Color.WHITE); }
        else { body.setBackground(Color.BLUE); }
    pane.setViewportView(body); }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could just make an example that demonstrates what you want. Eg. A JFrame, with a content pane that has a BorderLayout, then add/remove some components.

Comment: Thanks @matt. See SSCCE at bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understood BorderLayout, each time I added a JPanel (or any component) to the CENTER (or anywhere else in the layout) it would overwrite the old content.

No it doesn't overwrite the old content. The BorderLayout only keeps track of the last component added at any given constraint position. So when the layout manager is invoked, only that component is given a size/location.

However, any previous component will still have a size/location. Also because of how Z-Ordering works, the last component added is painted first. So the new component is painted and then the old component is painted over top of the new component.

To prevent this from happening you must remove the old panel first before adding the new panel.

> attempting to cycle different JPanel's for the body

The better solution is to use a `CardLayout` as it will manage the cycling of the panels for you. So add a panel using the `CardLayout` to the CENTER of the BorderLayout. Then add all the swappable panels to the card layout panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use CardLayout for more information and examples.

Edit:

> How would you "remove the old panel first"

Well, somewhere you must have code like:

```
panel.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

So if you want to swap panels you need code like:

```
panel.remove(panel1);
panel.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

So it is up to you to manage the reference to the last component added to the CENTER so you can manually remove it. This is why the CardLayout is easier, it does the management for you.

Edit2:

Didn't notice the scroll pane before. This makes it even easier. When you create the frame you just use:

```
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then when you want to swap panels its one line of code:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( panel2 );
```

Comment: You're right about CardLayout, but I was trying to avoid it (each panel requires several computations that I didn't want to make each time something changed; I could work around that but I'm not too familiar with CardLayout). How would you "remove the old panel first" is basically the crux of my question. Couldn't get `.removeLayoutComponent` to work, and remove/removeAll also didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up but like I said that wasn't working out for me. I realized that I forgot I was wedging a JScrollPane into the order and so I'm checking if that's my issue now.

Comment: @JamesLingo, You didn't mention the revalidate()/repaint() which is also important. `I forgot I was wedging a JScrollPane into the order` - if you are using a JScrollPane as the component on the content pane, then it is even easier as you just use `scrollPane.setViewportView(panel2);`. So my suggestion is to just add the JSdcrollPane to the content pane and then swap views of the scroll pane. No need to worry about a CardLayout or revalidate() and repaint() or anything else. See the second edit.

Comment: Thanks @camickr. Ok, I just switched my pane.add() to pane.setViewportView but now I'm just getting nada in the body. I'll post an edit above with my changes.

Comment: @JamesLingo, an edit won't help, I'm not going to read through all the code. You need to understand the basic concept first. Create a simple JFrame with a scroll pane added to the CENTER of the frame. Then create a JPanel with two buttons and add the panel to the SOUTH of the frame. When you click the first button it will display a lable in the scrollpane. Click the second button it will display a JButton in the scroll pane. This is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Once the SSCCE is working you can fix your program. If you can't get the SSCCE working you have you have simple code to post.

Comment: Okay I'll  put an SSCCE up but I've used remove/revalidate/repaint a bunch. I'm pretty sure there's some stupid glitch with the way I ordered my command or something. I don't understand why people always complain about the code not being included and then try to offer basic pointers after just reading the headline. I posted my code so you could see that I've tried using revalidate/repaint already. My edit was like 20 lines of code, but I'll whip up an SSCCE as well.

Comment: So SSCCE is in the body of my question. It works perfectly, but I don't understand what's different/where my error is...

Comment: @JamesLingo, `It works perfectly` - Right and you have proven that you only need a single statement to swap panels in the viewport. I still see you reference other methods of the pane like removeAll(), revalidate() and repaint(). If the SSCCE doesn't need them, why are then in your other code?  I would guess the problem is: `pane.removeAll();`. This is removing the viewport from the scroll pane (ie the SSCCE doesn't work if you add this statement to it). Also, a SSCCE should contain a main() method to display the GUI.

Comment: Stripping out the left over .removeAll() did it. Thanks.